# Setting connection collation in master for slave replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, master-slave-replication

I am trying to replicate a MySQL 8 server (master) to MySQL 5.7 (slave) instance. I know it is not officially supported, but the thing is we need to use a service that has only supports MySQL 5.7.

I know there are a few collations that are not available in MySQL5.7 which are present in MySQL8. For that, i converted all tables from `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` to `utf8mb4_general_ci` as our data values are supported by both, so I was able to do this without any consequences.

I have also set the following settings in my master's configuration:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci; SET NAMES utf8mb4;'
```

which yields me the following: (I am not connected as superuser)

```
mysql80> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Now I have narrowed it down to this that my `collation_connection` is the culprit because `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is not part of MySQL57. Due to which I get the following error on slave:

```
Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'database'. Query: 'BEGIN'
```

Is there any way to force my master instance to use `utf8mb4_general_ci` instead of `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all the Stored Routines; capture the ability to re-CREATE them.
2. Change the `DEFAULT COLLATION` for each `DATABASE` that had such routines.
3. `DROP` those routines.
4. Re-CREATE them.
5. `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` (etc) to verify that the collation is compatible with 5.7.

Comment: I have one stored procedure, does triggers have the same effect?

Comment: @echo_salik - Do step 5 to check.

Comment: Still getting this error: `Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'xxxx'. Query: 'BEGIN'`

Comment: my db collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci` and all tables have this collation. I only had one procedure in my db, and i did what you suggested. It does show `general_ci` now.

Comment: @echo_salik - What else is in `xxxx`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE DATABASE xxxx;` and anything else that might have a collation.

Comment: it's this: `CREATE DATABASE \`xxxx\` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */`

Comment: also when i dump using: `sudo mysqldump --no-data xxx > struct.sql`. I get no place with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, besides this line: `/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */;`

Comment: @echo_salik - Change that one!  In case you don't know, that comment says "If running 5.0.1 or newer, then do this SET.".  (Removing the line might also work.)

Comment: @echo_salik - I had another thought...  Use the 5.7 version of `mysqldump` to take the dump.

Comment: Yeah but i can use `sed` to change that. I can create and load a dump.I just can't replicate it.

Comment: Hmmm, I have run out of ideas.

Comment: thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but this might help others.
You have written: `init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci; SET NAMES utf8mb4;'`
These statements should be the other way: `init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4; SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci;'`
as the `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` will also change the collation_connection which would undo your previous statement.